# Implementing the GROUP BY oracle query causing: not a GROUP BY expression in Ruby

Tags: oracle

My **RUBY** code executes a oracle query in the following way, but I seem to be getting the error:

> Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
SELECT
  "REQUESTS".*
FROM
  "REQUESTS"
WHERE
  (
    customer_id = 1
    AND request_method != 'OPTIONS'
    AND request_time BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-29 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP(
      '2021-11-05 23:59:59.000999',
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
    )
  )
GROUP BY
  "REQUESTS"."REQUEST_TIME"
```

Initially the code which is translated into the above mentioned select query is:

```
requests = Request.where("customer_id = ? AND request_method != ? AND request_time BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')", customer.id, 'OPTIONS', start_time, end_time).group('date(request_time'))
```

The

```
.group('date(request_time') is translated in oracle to: GROUP BY date(request_time)
```

but it didn't seem to work either which was the original query, and the reason is because Oracle doesn't have this functionality , so I changed it and have been trying in differnt ways but can't seem to figure out why the group by expression wont work.

Comment: Because you group by a single column, but request all the columns. Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848). And it's totally unclear why you tagged SQLite alongside Oracle, because they are completely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select *` means "select all columns".

Group by clause says `group by request_time`, which is only one column, and that just won't work.

You'll have to apply `group by` to **ALL** columns (specified one-by-one), or - simpler - use `select distinct`.

Basically, we use `group by` when there's an aggregation in `select` column list. If there's none, you don't `group by`.

What you'll really do depends on what you *want* to do, i.e. which result you expect.

Comment: Thanks! The distinct seems to have fixed the issue. Appreciate the help and support :)